How to get icon inside Combobox?
In my FluentUI combobox in React, my icon appears outside of the field. Adjusting pading and margin doesn't seem to help. How can I do this?
const searchInputStyles = mergeStyles({
  display: 'inline-block',
  fontStyle: 'normal',
  fontWeight: 'normal',
  speak: 'none',
  fontFamily: 'FabricMDL2Icons',
  color: 'rgb(96, 94, 92)',
  fontSize: 16,
  height: 18,
  pointerEvents: 'initial',
  position: 'absolute',
  right: '32px',
  padding: '5px',
  cursor: 'pointer',
  '-webkit-font-smoothing': 'antialiased',
});



I don't think we have enough information yet to solve this. However, from what you have shown us it looks as though the icon is being positioned absolute so we need to see which is the closest ancestor that has a position in relation to which it can be positioned.
